# How to get find out if there is a missing dates in snowflake database and get the values of the missing dates based on the value of other dates

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a list of dates and Serial numbers and I want to get the values for all columns from each date in snowflake database. If the date is available in this database, I  can get the values of the columns selected from the database, but if the date is not available in this database, I should get the next date and the values from all columns from upcoming date from the database. Also, I would like to inform you the database which I am working on is a big database (TB).

This is an example:

Date           SN        Output

2020-08-18    SSK00100     7

2020-08-19    SSK00100     15

2020-10-20    SSK00100     12

2020-10-21    SSK00100     19

2021-01-05    SSK00105    101

2021-01-08    SSK00106    112

This is the output, I am looking for:

```
Date        SN       Output_1
```

2020-08-19    SSK00100     15       (for the date: 2020-08-19, I should get this data)

if the date is not available in the database, for example '2021-01-07', I should get this data for each column:

Date            SN       Output_1

2021-01-08      SSK00106    112

This is my code:

## Import packages

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

## src –> Four python files: get data, load data, splitting data, and Model building

from src.load_data import run_query

from IPython.display import display

from bisect import bisect_left

import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

from scipy import stats

import matplotlib.style as style

from six import string_types

## Code

def sql_fun (serial, start):

```
where_clause = f"SER_NUM='{serial}'" + "and " + f"OCUR_TS ='{start}'"

sql = f"""
        with grouped_table as (
           select Date,
                  SN,
                  Output,
                  count(Output) over (order by Date) as _grp
           from "CD_EQUIP_DATA_PROD_DB"."EDW_BI_SL_M1"."EQP_EVNT_VIMS"
           where {where_clause}
           ORDER BY Date
        ), final_table as(
           select Date,
                  SN,
                  Output,
                  _grp,
                  first_value(Output) over (partition by _grp order by Date) as
                      Output_1
            from grouped_table
            where {where_clause}
            ORDER BY Date
        )
        select Date,
               SN,
               Output_1
        from final_table
        where {where_clause}
        ORDER BY Date

        """
df = run_query(sql, server="east-2")

return df
```

df_SSP00180_1 = sql_fun ('SSK00100','2020-08-19')

df_SSP00238_2 = sql_fun ('SSK00109','2021-01-07')

print (df_SSP00180_1)

print (df_SSP00238_2)

I need really to your help, thanks a lot

Comment: Anyone can help me in answering this question?

Comment: Can we make the question more concise? I'm having trouble understanding why all the Python code is relevant here